# How can I be downgraded to a lower league?

Tags: starcraft-2

Last season in Starcraft 2 I was ranked into platinum by deploying a simple Zerg rush strategy. I have not played since then, and I just got back into SC2 wanting to play a more realistic strategy.

The problem is that after my placement game, in which I was destroyed, I have been placed in the diamond league. Every game I am utterly destroyed by players over and over again.

How many times do I need to lose before I can be downgraded to a lower league?

Comment: haha "deploying a simple zerg rush stratergy".

Comment: Why don't you look at the bright side? You might want to stay in diamond league until you learn to win matches by actually dominating and not getting lucky.

Comment: As I believe, "leagues" are fairly abstract and don't correlate 100% with your true ranking.  Whatever your ELO(-like) number is, is all that matters for matchmaking.

Comment: Don't be a puss. The best way to learn is by getting your ass whooped.

Comment: So, were you downgraded? :)

Comment: @tenfour 15 losses later and still in diamond );

Comment: Even after the season 3 placement match?

Comment: @tenfour yep, I've played a few more games but iim still in diamond.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I got put in platinum due to 5 ridiculously easy placement matches. I lost a lot but learned a lot more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hidden MMR (ELO-like rating) will plummet below a diamond threshold even while you remain in Diamond. After just a few (~10) games losing against "evenly matched" opponents, you should start playing games where you are considered "favored", and losing them. Eventually you could theoretically be always matched with bronze, even though your publicly visible league does not necessarily need to match your MMR.

However, I have noticed that bnet seems to only stray so far from your league. I could be wrong about that one, but I know a gold-level friend of mine that, after 25 losses in a row, was still being matched with silver and gold players. They could have rules in place that you can't be matched with someone more than 1 league away from your own.

All this is beside the point at the moment. With the current ladder lock, you will not be demoted or promoted no matter how many losses you incur.

tl;dr: **You'll have to wait for the placement match in Season 3**.

Comment: Your losses during the ladder lock still affect your MMR rating so you could still drop down. Source: http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/2545809#blog

Comment: Your MMR can change, but you won't be demoted until you play a game once the next season starts. Source: eu.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/2545809#blog

Comment: Also Season3 is not resetting anything. YOu'll get another placement match and likely re-enter the same league as you do now..

Comment: Considering the ladder was locked for so long, a *lot* of people are changing leagues after the season 3 placement match. (including me - yay!)

Comment: When i was bronze (First place) i was matched against a Gold player.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1:**

Though my answer answers not exactly the question and I take a risk to get down-vote, I will ask: why do you want to be demoted?

If you are concerning that you are losing too many matches - just try to play better. In the previous season you worked well and got rating enough to be put into diamonds. That's great... Probably you lost some skills, but playing with diamonds with no care and fare that you can be downgraded will help you progress quickly and restore your skills

**Part 2:**

Guess, you need not to lose, but sometime you need to start win. Only after that, when you will start winning to plat level players, guess, you will be "promoted" into platinum leagues.

But again, my opinion that you are still too good for platinum... don't try to be downgraded!

Comment: As i eluded to before, i got to where i am now through zerg rushes. I would never make more than one drone and if my rush failed it was over. But yea, I have since been playing a few games and i have tried my hardest but have since been utterly crushed about 20 times.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I would recommend to go to any SC2 replay sites, choose 3-5 replays where Zerg win - and choose favorite of them. After that - look replays of that player (5-10 more or so) and try to think how he is winning. Nevertheless to you Zerg-rush strategy, you are in Diamond that mean you can do stuff properly... and after that practice.